# R: Putting Variables in order by a different variable

Tags: r

Once again I have been set another programming task and to most of which I have done, so a quick run through: I've had to take `n` amount of samples of multivariate normal distribution with dimension `p` (called it `X`) then to put it into a matrix (`Matx`) where the first two values in each row were taken and summed a long with a value randomly drawn from the standard normal distribution. (Call this vector `Y`) Then we had to order `Y` numerically and split it up into `H` groups, and then I had to find out the mean of each row in the matrix and now having to order then in terms of which `Y` group they were associated. I've struggled a fair bit and have now hit a brick wall. Quite confusing I understand, if anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated!

Task:Return the `p`x`H` matrix which has in the first column the mean of the observations in the first group and in the `H`th column the mean in the observations in the `H`th group.

Code:

```
library('MASS')
x<-mvrnorm(36,0,1)
Matx<-matrix(c(x), ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
v<-rnorm(6)
y1<-sum(x[1:2],v[1])
y2<-sum(x[7:8],v[2])
y3<-sum(x[12:13],v[3])
y4<-sum(x[19:20],v[4])
y5<-sum(x[25:26],v[5])
y6<-sum(x[31:32],v[6])
y<-c(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6)
out<-order(y)
h1<-c(out[1:2])
h2<-c(out[3:4])
h3<-c(out[5:6])
x1<-c(x[1:6])
x2<-c(x[7:12])
x3<-c(x[13:18])
x4<-c(x[19:24])
x5<-c(x[25:30])
x6<-c(x[31:36])
mx1<-mean(x1)
mx2<-mean(x2)
mx3<-mean(x3)
mx4<-mean(x4)
mx5<-mean(x5)
mx6<-mean(x6)
d<-c(mx1,mx2,mx3,mx4,mx5,mx6)[order(out)]
d
```

Comment: I'm not clear where you are stuck. plus you are ordering something that was already ordered, do you mean `c(mx1,mx2,mx3,mx4,mx5,mx6)[out]`?

Comment: Oh dear was I? I'm still trying to get to grips with R, it hasn't entriely clicked with me yet. Also thank you, that seems to have worked!

Comment: on a different note, your code seems terribly inefficient. doing each one of these operations by hand is not the way to go. you have to vectorise it. your vector `y` of sums can be obtained via `sapply(0 : 5, FUN = function(i) sum(x[(6 * i + 1) : (6 * i + 2)], v[i + 1]))`